# PHP 7 / Pear 1.10.1 / IIS 8 > Mail Function not working

Tags: php, windows, email, iis, pear

I just updated my IIS 8 PHP installation from 5.6 to 7.0 and noticed the Mail function on my webpage has stopped working.

I installed Pear again to the PHP 7 directory, so Pear is now running 1.10.1.

When I run command and type Pear build, I see the following error:
[Environment Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gsdi.jpg)

I've restarted the system a few times but it is still picking up the wrong information.

Any ideas on what to do???

Comment: Note: I installed PHP x64 - is Pear able to run in 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix my Mail error by reinstalled the extensions...

CMD > pear install Mail and pear install Net_SMTP

The build info still responds with an error.